# Meaning of "Too true, too true!"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I cannot find a satisfactory definition for the phrase:

"Too true, too true!"

Can anybody help?

Comment: There's a difference between 'too true' and 'very true'. Take a note!

Comment: @MaulikV: Actually, there isn't. If you take it literally there would be, but nobody says this literally!

Comment: @Harry: You tagged this question "meaning in context", but did not provide any context.

Comment: Best interpreted as "More true than I wish it were"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You think so? I would not use them in the same way.

Comment: I can find no evidence of the phrase being used in the way that Mauliv, Shadur, StoneyB and Kyle suggest, other than on this page itself.

Answer (score 31):

*Too true* is a response to being reminded of a distressing fact: it acknowledges the truth of the other person's observation while wishing that it were *not* true. The fact is truer than I like, hence *too* true.

Comment: Thanks, StoneyB! By far the best explanation that I got so far. In fact, you have ended my quest.

Comment: I don't agree with this.

Comment: In some contexts, maybe. Without any context, I would assume this shouldn't be taken literally, and means the same thing as "very true" or "yeah, good point".

Comment: @TimS. and Lightness: I don't think I've *ever* seen "too true" used in any *other* way than this; in particular, I don't think I've seen it treated as merely synonymous with "very true." Perhaps you should re-evaluate your impressions of the phrase, or at least provide some examples of the phrase being used in the looser/milder way?

Comment: My initial reaction upon reading the title was that someone was speaking the phrase with slight chagrin.

Comment: If it matters to anyone, I say 'too true, too true', 'Ahhhh I see', 'Ahhh good point', 'Ahhh yes' all synonymously - to mean that they have explained something and I understand.

Answer (score 5):

**"Too true, too true" is a colloquialism that means "yeah, good point".**

One might argue it's "too true" (a colloquial British corruption of simply "true") repeated for poetry.

If one were to take it literally, then it might imply that the subject is truer than desired, but this is not a phrase that gets used literally.

Comment: I have to disagree. I use this phrase in the literal sense quite often, and so do others I know. While it may not be used in the literal sense everywhere, I believe the literal usage is the correct (i.e. conventional) one, and that non-literal usage would be colloquial.

Comment: @John I have never, not once, heard it in its literal sense. It's never even occurred to me that anyone would use it that way. I conclude that this must be highly geospecific at best.

Comment: @Lightness, do you have any specific and unambiguous examples of the phrase being used in this way?

Comment: @KyleStrand: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=too+true

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit UrbanDictionary seems...well, suspect, as a source for examples, and even there the "homework" example fits StoneyB's meaning better than it fits the "synonymous with 'very'" meaning. (And if I saw the "hot girl" example in real life, rather than as a contrived example for UD, I'd assume the speaker used "too" as an indication that, regrettably, he considers the girl in question to be "out of his league".) I was expecting something out of, say, a British novel or TV show, since you indicate that your usage may be chiefly British; have anything like that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I expect that there *are* people who use "too" in the sense you're indicating, but I do not think that should be the go-to interpretation.

Comment: @Kyle: You asked for examples. Both of those are the sort of examples I would have written for you. I could either have copied them here, or simply linked you to there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22227/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @Kyle: I don't see why it should not be the go-to interpretation. Again, I have _never_ heard it used the way you claim and I cannot find any evidence that anyone away from this thread does so. I've provided evidence of the usage I know about. Can you now present some of yours?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See chat for four examples, including Shakespeare and Byron.

Comment: @Kyle: That is hardly evidence of current usage.

Comment: Anecdotally, I have also heard the phrase used literally in conversation, and have used it this way myself. I was actually very surprised that you and TimS objected to the literal meaning. Are you *sure* that the usages you've heard couldn't be taken in a literal sense? As I pointed out before, *both* of the UD examples could be taken literally.

Comment: Also, the non-Byron and non-Shakespeare examples are newer. The example found by John Doucette is from colloquial-seeming dialogue in a novel that appears very recent.

Comment: @Kyle: It's a historical novel, set in the past. It's a reach to suggest that this is "recent dialogue". Besides, I just found the phrase "I owe a man a debt that need's _[sic]_ repaying" later on in the same book.

Comment: I wish I had more examples for you. I haven't put any time in doing any formal research for it, though. So I may have to be content with your disbelief, though I _strongly_ stand by my position. It is possible that my understanding of the phrase is geospecific, as mentioned in previous comments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right about the "historical novel" thing, as well as the observation that the style of the book overall is pretty bad. Still, it seems you're willing to concede that the literal meaning *was* at one point the accepted meaning; this is a shift from your initial position that you'd "never, not once, heard it in its literal sense". My suggestion is that we both keep our ears and minds open and observe what usages we hear in the future, and consider whether either or both interpretation would make sense (or even ask the speaker, if possible).

Comment: @Kyle: That's not a shift from my initial position, though I concede my initial position was ambiguously presented: I was talking about real, live communication between two people, not including historical works of fiction. In that vein I still stand by it: I never have heard this phrase used literally, and would be extremely surprised to do so, in the UK, so much so that I very much doubt it is used as such in communication. Of course I can't guarantee that: no-one can!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps this is a geographic thing. I am Canadian, and Kyle's employer seems to be based in Canada also. Neither of us has ever heard a non-literal usage before (i.e. precisely the opposite of your experience). It seems like many usages could be _interpreted_ either way, so there is no way to determine usage without asking the speaker for their intent. Consequently, we might find (in either case), that the people around us have used it in a mixture of ways. However, like you, I have trouble believing anyone intentionally uses an interpretation other than my own!

Comment: @John: Yes I've suggested several times now that it's geospecific. Anyway, please note and be assured that this certainty is not my default stance, nor even my usual stance. It's this specific case!

Comment: Yes, I live in North America (USA, though, not Canada). I'm not quite convinced by the geospecific argument, though, because presumably all three of us are exposed to a pretty broad range of English dialects via books, TV, movies, and the internet. I continue to be surprised by @LightnessRacesinOrbit's certainty; why this phrase in particular?

Comment: I'll throw in another Canadian opinion: I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit in that I rarely (if ever) hear this to mean *literally* too true. Usually it's just just used to mean "very true" or something akin to "ain't that the truth."